# Rename multiple files with spaces and prepending a number to the filenames in bash

Tags: rename, filenames, date

This is a list of files I have:

```
$ ls -rt1
First Day in Tokyo.mp4
First Day in Seoul.mp4
Second Day in Beijing.mp4
Third Day in Bangcock!.mp4
Last Day in Singapore.mp4
$
```

What I want is:

```
01. First Day in Tokyo.mp4
02. First Day in Seoul.mp4
03. Second Day in Beijing.mp4
04. Third Day in Bangcock!.mp4
05. Last Day in Singapore.mp4
```

Any one liners?

Comment: Is the numbering supposed to be in that specific ordering, oldest to newest?

Comment: Possibly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116628/how-can-i-restore-file-timestamps-of-video-recordings-using-the-embedded-metadat

Comment: Yup, in that order. I want to number them based on the modified time as sorted by `ls -rt`

Comment: `ls -rt1 | awk '{printf("mv -v \"%s\" \"%.2d. %s\"\n",$0,NR,$0)}' | sh`?

Comment: @Cyrus Nice one. It works! I wonder if there is a simpler way :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
for file in *
do
    let ++i
    mv "$file" "$(printf '%02d. %s' "$i" "$file")"
done
```

Example:

```
$ cd "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ touch foo bar
$ for file in *
> do
>     let ++i
>     mv "$file" "$(printf '%02d. %s' "$i" "$file")"
> done
$ ls
'01. bar'  '02. foo'
```